# Problem with python indexing on multidimensional array

Tags: python-3.x, list

I have this problem where this function:

```
async def deal_with_output(duel, text_input, player):
    player_out, enemy_out = duel[0].ui_for(player, text_input)
    print(player_out[0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0])

    for output in [player_out, enemy_out]:
        msg_out = output[0]
        react_out = output[1]
        if msg_out:
            await duel[2][player].edit(content = msg_out)
        if react_out:
            await duel[2][player].clear_reactions()
            for reaction in react_out:
                await duel[2][player].add_reaction(reaction)
        player = not player#next loop will be for enemy
```

is calling  duel[0].ui_for(player, text_input):

```
def ui_for(self, player, input_text):
    return [['a',None],['b',None]]
```

and somehow print(player_out[0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0]) is outputting [['a',None],['b',None]]. I just wanted to get the 'a' individually.